# Is there a way to stop moving forward while aiming?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

I'm playing Assassin's Creed Origins on PS4 and every time I aim with the bow my character starts moving forward. I don't push the analog forward and to counter act this I need to run backwards against the forward movement. Am I doing something wrong or is it a setting that I'm missing?

Comment: Sounds a bit like symptoms I would expect on a worn controller.  Xbox Controllers seem to do this after a few years of use.

Comment: I have a new controller and this does this only for this game. If I don't touch the analog it will do this.

Comment: Which type of bow? Does this happen when standing still with a Predator Bow?

Comment: Every bow, including when I just want to stand.

Comment: Are you able to stand still without using a bow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the controller's left stick is slightly worn, and due to the sensitivity while aiming the slight forward position of the controller's left stick results in you moving forward. I verified this by switching controllers. Try cleaning your controller, or you may need to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

It's on the defaults aim (free aim) so that's why it's not making your Character. It's happend to me it's nothing to to with controllers it's the settings i have 2 of them and both brand new so its not worn out

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please, be clear on what you're explaining, as it's currently written it's hard to understand.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Could you please include details on which aiming setting you think the user should switch to? You can update your answer by clicking the "Edit" button on your post.